# Error in UNTIL property of iCalendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I tested this calendar on the icalendar validator ( http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/ )  It said, invalid property UNTIL, I was not able to find the reason why this came. Can someone pls help.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID;X-RICAL-TZSOURCE=TZINFO:-//com.denhaven2/NONSGML ri_cal gem//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20111106T192735Z
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20111107T190000Z
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20111107T180000Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20111106T192735Z
LAST-MODIFIED;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20111106T192735Z
UID:availability_slot332@chronus.com
DESCRIPTION:Availability slot from mentoring program
SUMMARY:Mentoring Slot
ORGANIZER:iitm_mentor2@chronus.com
RRULE;UNTIL=20111130T183000Z;WKST=MO:FREQ=DAILY
EXRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SA,SU
LOCATION:Los Angeles
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colon needs to go after RRULE, not after WKST, apparently:

```
RRULE:UNTIL=20111130T183000Z;WKST=MO;FREQ=DAILY
```